# Adding resources to forms in XNA

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I'm new to XNA, however I managed to develop a pac man game. Now I'm trying to add some forms to the game to be used as a log in screen,but due to being an XNA project I can't add pictures to the form, any help pls?

Thx for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XNA doesn't work like WinForms, it isn't a GUI editor. Like you said, you can't add windows controls to a XNA application (unless you use a workaround, but that's not necessary for a login screen)

You'll need to use Game States to determine what to draw/update based on which menu you're currently in. The APP Hub has an [example](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) for that.

Comment: Oh ok thx a lot, I'll check it out, also if you don't mind, do you know if it's possible to connect that to a database pls?

Thanks again

Comment: Definitely, you can connect to a database, like any C# application. MSDN has a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884(v=vs.90).aspx) for that.